# Sharing data between jetpack composables

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm pretty fresh to Jetpack compose and self teaching myself it after coming from a self taught python background
so bare with me while i learn please.

What i'm trying to achieve at the moment is to share data between composables in this case i'm trying to update the profileScreen from data stored from the EmployeeSettingsScreen but i keep getting empty results. Below is what i have so far

I have a bottomNavigationScreen which is called once a user logs in
In my head i call this the parent composable as it is what's called first before all the screens are set

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationScreen(
    loginNavController: NavController
) {
    val employeeSettingsViewModel: EmployeeSettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    val TAG = "BottomNavigationScreen"

    val sharedViewModel : SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val authRepository = AuthRepositoryLocal.current
        ... }
```

Next i have a EmployeeSettingsScreen
Which is the screen that shows the settings composables inside the bottomNavigation composable
and it has various text fields and buttons for the user to enter data into (not shown in the snippet)

```
@Composable
fun EmployeeSettingsScreen() {

    val employeeSettingsViewModel: EmployeeSettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val commonViewModel: CommonViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val commonUiState: CommonModel by commonViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    val uiState by employeeSettingsViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
        ... }
```

Next i have a EmployeeSettingsViewModel
which is responsible for updating the data class i have which is called
EmployeeSettingsModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class EmployeeSettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    employeeSettingsModel: EmployeeSettingsModel,
    private val commonViewModel: CommonViewModel,
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository,
    private val realtimeDatabaseViewModel: RealTimeDatabaseViewModel,
    private val cypherInstance: CryptoClass,
) : ViewModel()

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "EmployeeSettingsViewModel"
    private val SECURITYLIST = listOf("phoneNumber", "email", "age", "name")
}
val sharedViewModel : SharedViewModel = SharedViewModel(employeeSettingsModel)
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(employeeSettingsModel)
val uiState: StateFlow<EmployeeSettingsModel> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

fun setSharedData(employeeSettingsModel: EmployeeSettingsModel) {
    sharedViewModel.setSharedData(employeeSettingsModel)
}
... }
```

and the EmployeeSettingsModel snippet is

```
data class EmployeeSettingsModel (
    /**
     * This file typically holds a data class and does not usually do any
     * buisness logic. Here we will mainly store the employees main data
     *
     */

    val name: String = "",
    val email: String = "",
    val phoneNumber: String = "",
    val age: String = "",
...}
```

The above all seems to work as intended to this point. When i enter data into the
the settingsScreen composable it stores successfully the data into the dataclass
The problem i'm having is i've now moved onto a "profileScreen"
When i click the profile screen i want to display all the data found in the EmployeeSettingsModel
into various textfields etc in the profile screen( not shown in the snippets provided)
I thought maybe i need to have a sharedViewModel to share the data between different composables?

However... although the sharedData value reflects the correct data when i enter something into the
EmployeeSettingsScreen, when i go to the profileScreen the sharedData value is empty
I've tried to debug this but i'm now overly confused

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    employeeSettingsModel: EmployeeSettingsModel
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _sharedData = MutableStateFlow(employeeSettingsModel)
    val sharedData: StateFlow<EmployeeSettingsModel> get() = _sharedData.asStateFlow()

    fun setSharedData(data: EmployeeSettingsModel) {
        println("SharedViewModel: ${sharedData.value.country}")
        _sharedData.value = data
    }
}
```

and the profileScreen is

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val sharedData by sharedViewModel.sharedData.collectAsState() // Collect the shared data as StateFlow

    val commonViewModel: CommonViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    val uiState by when (LoggedInUser.registrationType.value) {

        "employee" -> sharedViewModel.sharedData
        //"employer" -> employerSettingsViewModel.uiState
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Invalid user type")
    }.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(sharedData) {
        println("The sharedData is currently $sharedData")
    }

        ... }
```

and finally my hilt appModule. NOTE: Still haven't worked out Hilt properly yet i'm only guessing i have it somewhat functional

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providecryptoClass(): CryptoClass {
        return CryptoClass()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginViewModel(authRepository: AuthRepository): LoginViewModel {
        return LoginViewModel(authRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthRepository(): AuthRepository {
        return AuthRepository()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRealTimeDatabaseViewModel(authRepository: AuthRepository, commonViewModel: CommonViewModel): RealTimeDatabaseViewModel {
        return RealTimeDatabaseViewModel(authRepository, commonViewModel)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCommonModel(): CommonModel{
        return CommonModel()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCommonViewModel(commonModel: CommonModel): CommonViewModel{
        return CommonViewModel(commonModel)

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideEmployeeSettingsModel(): EmployeeSettingsModel{
        return EmployeeSettingsModel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying to work this out , i may of stumbled across the issue by trial and error approach (well... more of a just try anything approach and hope). Mainly because i don't fully understand yet how the hilt thing works .

anyway, i moved `sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel` to the constructor in  in employeeSettingsScreen which ive done many times before, but hilt always complains about putting it there. anyway. i then added to my appModule

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedViewModel(employeeSettingsModel: EmployeeSettingsModel): SharedViewModel {
        return SharedViewModel(employeeSettingsModel)
    }
```

and now things seem to work as expected.

I think I need to find a dumbed down tutorial on hilt cause anything i read at the moment seems to be over complicated. Due to self learning, i learn better when it's familiar code to me where as all the tutorials go off on tangents with api calls, server poking and all sorts of things that make me go WTF ?

Anyway. Hope this helps someone in the future